# Deleting a File from Storage after Download

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, axios

I'm working on a media asset management system. I want the user to be able to fill out a form with file width, height, extension and colorspace, then transform the image and serve it back as a download.

I can get that to work by responding to the Post-Request with the URL of the newly created file.

What I want is for that file to be deleted after download or after some time.
(Or, preferably, a way to use laravels download() Response, which I apparently can't use inside an Axios/Ajax post request).

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you want to delete the file after download then unlink the file when download completes successfully. Or if you want to delete after a specific time then you need to use cronjob.

Comment: There's not a lot of context here about the behavior you're looking for, your question is not specific, there are no code examples, and there isn't a list of things you've tried or researched.  Please put in the amount of effort in crafting your question as you'd like us to put into answering it.  This may seem harsh, but there are a ton of questions that come through here, and if we're not exactly sure what we're supposed to be solving, then your answer is going to be a non-answer.

Comment: @MichaelMiller I'm sorry, I'm rapidly approaching a deadline and at some point my brain just stopped working. I'll add some more information.

Comment: Hey @radi0active, please don't be sorry...  I've received this response from others countless times...  I hope that makes you feel better about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two ways you can do this.**

Let's assume you have a file in `storage/app/download.zip`:

**1.** Because Laravel uses Symfony's HttpFoundation internally, you can use the  [`deleteFileAfterSend`](https://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.html#method_deleteFileAfterSend) method:

```
public function download()
{
    return response()
        ->download(storage_path('app/download.zip'))
        ->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
}
```

**2.** Create a [Terminable Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#terminable-middleware) that deletes the file after the download response was prepared.

```
class StorageDownload
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        \Storage::delete('download.zip');
    }
}
```

You'll need to [register the middlware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#registering-middleware) and [assign it to your route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes) for it to work.

---

As for triggering the download using JavaScript, something as trivial as setting the window location will work:

```
axios
    .post('files/export/' + file.id, formData)
    .then(function() {
        window.location = 'files/download/' + file.id
    });
```

Don't worry, this will not navigate away from your current page, it will just trigger the download.

Comment: The JavaScript download via window.location is exactly what I have implemented at the moment. What I can't seem to wrap my head around is how to handle response()->download() inside my axios function.

Comment: Why would you need to handle the response download? That is for the browser to handle. If you have a download response, the only thing that should happen is for the browser to display the save dialog to allow the user to specify where to save the file. Axios has nothing to do with this, the download should not be triggered asynchronously, it should be a synchronous request. You might want to edit your question to include the JS code so we can see what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I'm sending my form data through a post request via axios.post('files/export/' + file.id, formData); The response()->download() inside my controller works as far as I can tell through developer tools, but it doesn't trigger a download.

Comment: One approach would be to send a post request with whatever parameters you need to generate the modified image/file (but not provide the download). When that request is finished it means that the new file is in storage and can be downloaded. So when that request is done you should trigger the download from a separate download url. I've updated my answer to include some sample code of how that might look.

Comment: Right, I get the idea! But the user is setting the file extension dynamically through the form, so the path i'd have to redirect to would be /files/download/{filename}/{extension} for my download() function to know what path to respond with. But now I simply get redirected to /files/download/filename.png instead of getting a download prompt. I'm sure I'll hate myself for being so dense but I can't seem to figure this out by myself. /// Nevermind, I'm too tired! I forgot to compile my JavaScript. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

for me , i like to handle this case using cron

you can read details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling)

add any column to check it's been downloaded or not (e.g status with value 0 or 1)

and you can create accessor on your model to count the date diff

```
public function getRangeDateAttribute(){
 $today = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
 $downloadDate =  $this->created_at;
 $datediff =  $today->diffInDays($downloadDate);
 return $datediff
}
```

then sample code inside task scheduling :

```
if($media->status == 1 || $media->rangeDate > 7 ){ //checking the status & range date passed specific days you wanted
do whatever you wanted here
}
```